# Twilio Programmable Chat with React Native

Tags: react-native, twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

I am trying to add Twilio Chat to my react native project. I'm getting an error with the name `SyncError` and code 0. I'm just trying to confirm it's connected at this point. Here's my basic setup.

Import at the top

```js
import {Client as Chat} from 'twilio-chat'
```

Inside my class

```js
componentDidMount = async () => {
    console.log(Chat);
    const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('auth-token');
    axios.get(config.apiUrl + '/chat/details', { headers: { Authorization: token } })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        Chat.create(res.data.twilioToken)
          .then(client => {
            console.log('client', client);
            this.subscribeToAllChatClientEvents(client);
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.log('There was an error', error);
          });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      })
  }
```

The error also mentions an "Unhandled promise rejection" but I've included any `catch` blocks where needed.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: At what point are those errors thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone getting the same issue. I realised that the problem was in my server code as I wasn't creating the twilio jwt token properly.

Answer (score 0):

There's likely a problem with the token.

In my experience, I got a good token from my backend server and I save it on AsyncStorage. However, after a while the token wasn't working anymore.

I solved it by requesting the server a new twilio token each time I needed to instantiate the SDK client.